# Arduino software power switch for SD card

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sd-card

Don't beat me here but I'm pretty new to the micro controller stuff...
I try to build an data logger and need to save as much as possible power in the idle (sleep) state. Is there a way to switch of the power to the level controller and to the SD card module by the software before going into the sleep mode?
I use an Arduino Uno board with connected level controller for the signal wires to the SD card. The SD card is power through the Arduino board right now.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Atmega328p datasheet and read the section "power management and sleep modes".

Comment: How are you powering the Arduino?

Comment: The arduino is going to be powered by a battery pack (3x 1,5V mignons). I know they will not last long with the arduino board but this is just for testing. I'm going to set up the final data logger with a bar bone.

Comment: @shuttle87, I'm not looking for the sleep mode but for a setup where I can switch of the power to the SD card module by the software. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda depends on how you are powering the sdcard now. If you are using less than 40mA you can power these things directly from an IO port which you can invert when you are trying to turn it off. Makre sure you put these on separate registers if you can. Each port register has a 100mA max.

Otherwise you could use a simple transistor setup to drive more power and turn that on/off from IO.

Edit for question below

I will assume you are using the UNO or equivalent which as the ATmega328p onboard to drive it. Here is the pinout for the chip which shows the Arduino mappings:
http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168

You will notice that the pin names start with either PB, PC or PD. This is Port register B, Port register C and Port register D. PB and PD have 8 pins and PC has 7. You would just need to make sure you are keeping in mind that there are power limitations on groups of pins. Each pin can do 40mA max (without causing damage) but that doesn't mean you can run every pin to its max. They can theoretically run up to approx 80mA but you will be doing damage at that draw.

See here for a detail on the maximum currents for the pin map
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations

Comment: Hello djUniversal, thanks for your answer. It makes sense and I will check that out. But could you explain how I put something on different registers? Thanks.

Comment: See my further comments above

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I'll do as I was told.